# How to accept a WebSocket asynchronously?

Tags: java, asynchronous, websocket, playframework

I have an Play application that handles WebSocket requests. The routes file contains this line:

```
GET  /testsocket  controllers.HomeController.defaultRoomSocket
```

An already working, synchronous version looks like this: (adapted from 2.7.x docs)

```java
public WebSocket defaultRoomSocket() {
    return WebSocket.Text.accept(
        request -> ActorFlow.actorRef(MyWebSocketActor::props, actorSystem, materializer));
  }
```

As stated in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaWebSockets#Accepting-a-WebSocket-asynchronously I changed the signature to

```java
public CompletionStage<WebSocket> defaultRoomSocket(){
   //returning a CompletionStage here, using the "ask pattern"
   //to get the needed Flow from an other Actor
}
```

From here I run into the following problem:

```
Cannot use a method returning java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage[play.mvc.WebSocket] as a Handler for requests
```

Further more, 'WebSocket' has no TypeParameter, as the documentation suggests. What is the appropriate way to accept a WebSocket request async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation indeed need to be updated, I think some bits were missed in the refactoring of the websockets in [#5055](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/5055).

To get async processing, you should use the `acceptOrResult` method that takes a `CompletionStage` as return type instead of a flow. This can then return either a `Result` or an Akka `Flow`, using a functional programming helper (`F.Either`). In fact, here's how the `accept` method is implemented:

```java
public WebSocket accept(Function<Http.RequestHeader, Flow<In, Out, ?>> f) {
   return acceptOrResult(
       request -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(F.Either.Right(f.apply(request))));
}
```

As you can see, all it does is call the async version with a `completedFuture`.

To fully make it async and get to what I think you're trying to achieve, you'd do something like this:

```
public WebSocket ws() {
    return WebSocket.Json.acceptOrResult(request -> {
        if (sameOriginCheck(request)) {
            final CompletionStage<Flow<JsonNode, JsonNode, NotUsed>> future = wsFutureFlow(request);
            final CompletionStage<Either<Result, Flow<JsonNode, JsonNode, ?>>> stage = future.thenApply(Either::Right);
            return stage.exceptionally(this::logException);
        } else {
            return forbiddenResult();
        }
    });
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private CompletionStage<Flow<JsonNode, JsonNode, NotUsed>> wsFutureFlow(Http.RequestHeader request) {
    long id = request.asScala().id();
    UserParentActor.Create create = new UserParentActor.Create(Long.toString(id));

    return ask(userParentActor, create, t).thenApply((Object flow) -> {
        final Flow<JsonNode, JsonNode, NotUsed> f = (Flow<JsonNode, JsonNode, NotUsed>) flow;
        return f.named("websocket");
    });
}

private CompletionStage<Either<Result, Flow<JsonNode, JsonNode, ?>>> forbiddenResult() {
    final Result forbidden = Results.forbidden("forbidden");
    final Either<Result, Flow<JsonNode, JsonNode, ?>> left = Either.Left(forbidden);

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(left);
}

private Either<Result, Flow<JsonNode, JsonNode, ?>> logException(Throwable throwable) {
    logger.error("Cannot create websocket", throwable);
    Result result = Results.internalServerError("error");
    return Either.Left(result);
}
```

(this is taken from the [play-java-websocket-example](https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.7.x/play-java-websocket-example), which might be of interest)

As you can see, it first goes through a few stages before returning either a websocket connection or a HTTP status.

Comment: Thanks for giving the hint to the examples. Your guess was right, that exactly solves what I was trying to achieve. At least for me, this example is a better showcase of how to use `acceptOrResult` (compared to the documentation/tutorial)